# Does the name Frisk mean anything?

Tags: undertale

In Undertale, the names behind character usually have a meaning behind them. For example, Toriel is supposed to be like a Tutorial, or Sans and the font.

Does the name Frisk have a meaning behind it?

Comment: Sans is named for 'Comic Sans'. You might note he's a bit of a joker as well... a 'comic' even...

Comment: I totally missed toriel being short for tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Undertale wiki](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Frisk):

> Depending on the ending that the player is moving towards, Frisk can
>   be depicted as friendly or cold. In the Pacifist Ending, characters
>   such as Asriel make an emphasized note about Frisk's **kindness,
>   understanding, and grace**. This is also the only ending when Frisk's
>   name is given, which implies that this is their **true character and
>   personality.**

And from the definition of the name:

> To "Frisk" means to skip or leap playfully, or to pat down on someone,
>   looking for a hidden item. "Frisk" is the Swedish and Norwegian word
>   for "healthy", and the Danish word for "fresh." "Frisky" means
>   "**playful and full of energy**."

Thus, Frisk's true personality is that of a kind/playful person who's healthy/full of energy.

Comment: Everytime you think you learnt everything about a game...